# Cannot update DropdownButtonFormField field value in flutter with getx obs

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, obs, flutter-dropdownbutton

I am using getx obs with fluter and the below is json response.

```
[{"id":1,"designation":"Deputy General Manager"},{"id":2,"designation":"Executive Director, Technical Operations","designation_short_code":"ED, TO"},{"id":3,"designation":"Manager","designation_short_code":"M"},{"id":4,"designation":"Sr. Manager","designation_short_code":"Sr. M"}]
```

In controller I am using--

```
var listData = List<dynamic>.empty(growable: true).obs;
 var designation = 1.obs;

  void setDesignation(int value) {
    designation.value = value;
  }
```

I am getting the above json response based on api call under listData.

In UI I am using the below code..

```
Obx(() => DropdownButtonFormField<dynamic>(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Designation',
                            labelText: 'Select Designation',
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                            ),
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow),
                          ),
                          hint: Text(
                            'Select Designation',
                          ),
                          onChanged: (selectedValue) {
                            designation_controller
                                .setDesignation(selectedValue);
                          },
                          value:
                              designation_controller.designation.value.toInt(),
                          items: designation_controller.listData.map((map) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem(
                              child: Text(map['designation']),
                              value: map['id'],
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                        )),
```

My problem is whenever I select designation it is not updating though my api end point is hitting with 200 response.

Can anyone help me please.
Thanks in advnace.

Comment: Facing the same issue but did you tried using update method inside controller?

Comment: Where are you setting the value of `listData`?

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed problem. My problem was in the below code

```
updateData(
    controller.userData[0]['id'], 
    controller.designationEdittingTextController.text
)
```

I have changed `controller.designationEdittingTextController.text` to `controller.designationEdit.value` as below

```
updateData(
    controller.userData[0]['id'],
    controller.designationEdit.value
)
```

Thanks